# Showing that G is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, proof-writing

Let $|G|=200$. Show that G is solvable.

My beginning of the proof:

1. $|G|=200=2^3*5^2$
2. Let $n_5$ be the number of Sylow p-subgroups. Then $n_5|8$ and $n_5\equiv1 mod5$. And it implies that $n_5=1$.
3. From 2. we know that there exists $N$, such that $N\unlhd G$ and $|N|=25$.

What should be my next steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

1. $\;N\;$ is solvable (why?)
2. $\;G/N\;$ is also solvable (again, why?)

and thus $\;G\;$ is solvable.

Comment: Can I assume that $N \cong \mathbb{Z}_{25}$?

Comment: @Novsar Of course not, but that doesn't matter: there are only two subgroups up to isomorphism of order $\;25\;$ and they both are abelian.

Comment: @Novsar: I don't believe so, though you can conclude that $N$ is abelian. It's not essential, though. What do you know about $p$-groups?

Comment: @AWertheim I know that every $p$-group is solvable... so my $N$ is solvable.

Comment: Well, that's helpful for 2. above, though it also solves 1. and the problem altogether .  For 1. it is enough to know that any group of order the square of a prime is abelian,

Comment: So would it be correct if I said that $N$ is isomorphic to an abelian group, so it is solvable. And that $|G/N|=8=2^3$, so it is a $p$-group and it is solvable. And from the theorem from my lecture (and your advice) I can conclude then G is solvable?

Comment: If "the theorem from your lecture" is the one that says that a solvable extension by a solvable group yields a solvable group then yes, you can.

Comment: The theorem is: $G$ is solvable $\Leftrightarrow G/N$ is solvable and $N$ is solvable.

Comment: Yes, that's the one...